# Using width auto on a table cell in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

Basically,

I have a table with 4 columns 3 of them have a fixed width and 1 has a width of auto. At the moment it's not spanning to make the row fit the entire table container.

This is how it should work:
http://jsfiddle.net/05ky1xfx/4/

Should span the rest of the table row and it doesn't is there anything i should adjust to make this happen so that the `width: auto;` spans the row?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking. Your jsfiddle seems to work. In fact, [you don't even need `width:auto`](http://jsfiddle.net/05ky1xfx/8/). What's going wrong?

Comment: Oh I see your live page in your edit history. There are `display:block` declarations on your `<tbody>` and `<tr>` that are messing things up. `style.css line:1711` and `style.css line:1716`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct the table by removing `display:block` from the `<tbody>` and `<tr>`.

Applying `display:block` changes those elements into block elements rather than table elements and interrupts the table flow.

Here are the changes I made:

**style.css line:1711**

```
.forum-table, .forum-table > tbody {
  /*display: block;*/
  width: 100%;
}
```

**style.css line:1716**

```
.forum-table > tbody > tr {
  position: relative;
  /*display: block;*/
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

Also, you do not need `width:auto` on the `<td>`:

**style.css line:1732**

```
.forum-table > tbody > tr > td.forum-name {
  /*width: auto;*/
}
```

Here's a [**DEMONSTRATION** (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/yyLg3spo/embedded/result/).

I have not included all of your resources, so some things (e.g. images, javascript) area broken. But the table layout in question remains intact.

Answer (score 0):

**Convert Pixels to Percents**

One good easy solution that is the *standard* used to convert pixel based websites to responsive percent designs is to use a set formula to convert pixel widths to their percent equivalent.

The formula is:

> *Formula:* target ÷ context = results x 100 = final percent results

The target is the pixel size of the element that needs converting.

The context is the pixel size of your website.

So your formulas would be:

> *First Cell:* 52px ÷ 1170px = 0.044 x 100 = 4.44%
>
> *Last Cell:* 250px ÷ 1170px = 0.1236 x100 = 21.36%

Now you can covert all your cell sizes to percents for consistent, reliable results. So your cell sizes will be 4.44% for cell 1, 59.20% for cell 2, 15% for cell 3, and 21.36% for cell 4.

*Note: If the conversion requires exact measurements, than use more decimal places.*

Here is an easy to use online calculator: http://rwdcalc.com/

Good overview for converting pixel wireframes to percent: http://www.awmcreative.com/css/creating-a-flexible-grid-from-pixels-to-percentages/

Comment: It's a good solution because it uses percent widths, and doesn't rely on all the different browsers/devices trying to accurately calculate pixels, percents and auto all in one table.

Comment: Yeah, you can't expect something to be a relative width to other static widths and for it to always be proportionate.